# Created a response listening service with php and curl just like paypal IPN

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I am new to php web services and i have asked this question before but could not get useful solutions so i have tried to rephrase it. i am trying to listen to a response from an API and update my database like what is done by the paypal IPN service. The script that i have so far works well when you run it in the browser and i am a geting my a json response back via POST, but the API later sends another response without the involvement of the browse/client and i want it to communicate to my php script in the server and update the database. The API has a notifyURL field that it requires for it to send these notifications and i have set it to the same file that sends the request. Below is the code that i have so far:

```
    if($ch !== false){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

            //Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");


            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


            //Set the content type to application/json
           // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       'Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose',
       'Content-length:' . strlen($jsonDataEncoded))
     );
    }


    //Execute the request
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($result === false){
      curl_close($ch);
      echo "Error".curl_errno($ch). "\n";
    }else {
      curl_close($ch);

      $decoded = json_decode($result, true);

      // echo '<pre>';
      // var_dump($decoded["paymentAmount"]["totalAmountCharged"]);
      // die;

      $data['unique_id'] = $decoded["clientCorrelator"];
      $data['subscriber_number'] = $decoded["endUserId"];
      $data['payment_status'] = $decoded["transactionOperationStatus"];
      $data['payment_gross'] = $decoded["paymentAmount"]["totalAmountCharged"];
      $data['txn_id'] = $decoded["ecocashReference"];

      $this->payments->insertTransaction($data);
      die;
```

What do i need to add to the script for me to achieve my goal using curl and php. The API returns the json response below and i am trying to listen for it and update certain fields into the database.

```
  {"id":71109,"version":0,"clientCorrelator":"58ada3aec8615","endTime":null,"startTime":1487774641697,"notifyUrl":"http://website/ecocash_send/transaction","referenceCode":"17589","endUserId":"774705932","serverReferenceCode":"2202201716440169792864","transactionOperationStatus":"PENDING SUBSCRIBER VALIDATION","paymentAmount":{"id":71110,"version":0,"charginginformation":{"id":71112,"version":0,"amount":1,"currency":"USD","description":" Bulk Sms Online payment"},"chargeMetaData":{"id":71111,"version":0,"channel":"WEB","purchaseCategoryCode":"Online Payment","onBeHalfOf":"PAMONMEFT","serviceId":null},"totalAmountCharged":null},"ecocashReference":"MP170222.1644.A00059","merchantCode":"0000","merchantPin":"000","merchantNumber":"771999313","notificationFormat":null,"serviceId":null,"originalServerReferenceCode":null}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be nothing special about the script that responds to the PayPal IPN like call.

All it need to do is be there waiting for the other API to launch it, know what parameters to expect, have a robust error reporting mechanism i.e. save the errors somewhere that you can review them later, or email them to an email account you will look at regularly.

Other than that the usual database access code is all that should be necessary.

Of course you cannot get it to throw anything at your browser as there is no browser in the process.

Comment: Thank you. So are you saying that this php and curl script is enough to get the response from the API?

Comment: I have to admit, I am not sure why you are using cURL there, surely the API will pass you some data describing what it is telling you. All you need to do is amend your database with that information

Comment: I am using curl to send my json and get the response on: **$result = curl_exec($ch);**

Comment: But surely you are receiving this IPN like information after you have made your initial communication to the other API, and this is just the other API's method of telling you something has or has not happened based upon what you have already asked the API to do

Comment: Yes i guess this is what is going. So are you saying there is a better way of doing it or i need to add something. I am sorry i am new to this so any examples will help

Comment: Show me what gets sent to you by the API in this process

Comment: the json response is too long to send on comments. but its just a json array that i sent by the api. i am struggling to  create the server file that listens to the api response

Comment: So edit your question, using the edit link below the question area

Comment: thanks. i have edited the question and i have added the json response that i get from the API